# Using arrays and rand to count the number of instances of an integer between 1-10?

Tags: c++, arrays

I am prompted to

> Create a length 11 array, and to use a for loop to create 1500 random integers ranging between 1 and 10, incrementing array locations inside the loop to count the instances of each number 1-10 that are displayed randomly

Apparently, components I need are:

```
int array[11] = {0};
int i;
i = rand() % 10 + 1;
arr[i]++;
```

I've tried whit something like this:

```
for (int i = rand() % 10 + 1; i < 11;   ;)
{
    array[i]++;
}
```

I don't get any output when I run it. I'm a bit stuck, if anyone could help. Thank you very much!

Comment: When you're stuck, **try something simpler.** In this case, try writing code that generates one random number in the range [1,10] and prints it out. When that works, try three random numbers. Meanwhile, try writing code that constructs an array of length 11, initialized to zeroes, and prints it out. Then try incrementing a couple of its elements. When those two pieces work, try linking them together. Small steps.

Comment: Which part of this code should produce output?

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering if you are describing this?

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    int array[11] = {0};

    for (int i = 0; i < 1500; ++i) {
        int j = rand() % 10 + 1;
        array[j]++;
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < 11; ++i) {
        std::cout << i << '\t' << array[i] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want:

```
//create array
int array[11];
//fill array with zeros
for(int i = 0; i <= 10; ++i) {
    array[i] = 0;
}
//count random numbers
for(int i = 0; i < 1500; ++i) {
    int randomNumber = rand() % 10 + 1;
    ++array[randomNumber];
}
//print result
for(int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i) {
    printf("Number %d was generated %d times", i, array[i]);
}
```

This is a pure c way, of course you can use `std::cout` for printing, too.
By the way: this way index 0 is wasted, but it is how you described it.

Answer (score 0):

Using your code and applying minimum changes to your own code and using the components given here is the single loop implementation.

```
int array[11] = {0}; //COMPONENT 1
int k=0;
int i; //COMPONENT 2
for(int k=0; k < 1500;k++)
{ 
  int i = rand() % 10 + 1; //COMPONENT 3
  array[i]++; //COMPONENT 4 
}
//TO CHECK ANSWER
for(i=0;i<11;i++)
cout<<array[i]<<endl;
```

Also, I agree to a user jjj's observation that the index 0 is wasted